# I am trying to register my DbContext as a service in my program.cs using .NET 6 in Visual Studio 2022, but I get an error on. GetConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am getting an error saying configuration does not include a definition for `GetConnectionString`.

This is my `Program.cs` file:

```
    global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    global using LearningBlazor.Shared;
    global using System.Configuration;
    global using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    
    app.Run();
```

This is how I am trying to register the `AppDbContext`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    });
```

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=CLARENCE\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DDME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: post your appsettings.json

Comment: @MestreDosMagros, I have added it to the post.

Comment: @RyanWilson, It still doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I found out that I have to say `builder.Congiguration` instead of just configuration like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
                         //the change occurs here.
                         //builder.cofiguration and not just configuration
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
});
```

Comment: There's on `Configuration` variable in your code so why did you expect to be able to use it? The `Configuration` you were trying to use is the `System.Configuration` namespace. Had you posted the actual compilation error this would be clear.